# Зафиксировать меню при достижении объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть вот такой js

```
var StickyElement = function (node) {
    var doc = $(document), fixed = false, anchor = node.find('.left-menu-anchor'), content = node.find('.left-menu');

    var onScroll = function (e) {
        var docTop = doc.scrollTop(), anchorTop = anchor.offset().top;

        console.log('scroll', docTop, anchorTop);
        if (docTop > anchorTop) {
            if (!fixed) {
                anchor.height(content.outerHeight());
                content.addClass('fixed');
                fixed = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (fixed) {
                anchor.height(0);
                content.removeClass('fixed');
                fixed = false;
            }
        }
    };

    $(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
};

var demo = new StickyElement($('#left-menu'));
```

и html к нему

```
<div style="height: 8000px;">
    <div id="left-menu">
        <div class="left-menu-anchor"></div>
        <div class="left-menu fixed">
            <div class="aside-title">Меню</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="anchor-bott">Останаливаем меню</p>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы при достижении элемента `anchor-bott` скролинг меню остановился и меню зафиксировалось над этим элементом?

Рабочий пример тут — https://jsfiddle.net/mvo1rh3L/

Comment: а обычное `position:sticky;` не вариант ? https://demo.htmlhook.ru/css3/position/sticky.htm

Comment: Какая разница?  Ок. Сделал второй вариат с `position:sticky;` https://jsfiddle.net/mvo1rh3L/2/

Comment: ну это у вас пустой контент , на бейте тестовыми данными , я не понимаю в чём проблема у вас

Comment: И ? ) https://jsfiddle.net/mvo1rh3L/3/

Comment: https://codepen.io/LenskyUser/pen/dRbNdj?editors=1100  вот так